# ¿Cuántas líneas es recomendable tener en el método main para proyectos medianos?

Tags: java, netbeans

Como proyecto de la universidad, estoy haciendo un mini sistema de Gestión de Inventario para un emprendimiento pequeño con Java usando Netbeans. Me llamó la atención que mi método main (solo tengo uno), tenga tan solo 13 líneas de código:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras otras clases de los Formularios, como las que se ven en el navegador de paquetes, llegan a tener sus 1200 líneas de código: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber qué es lo que ustedes suelen incluir en el método main de sus proyectos, además de hacer visibles los formularios y cosas así. Además quisiera saber si es buena práctica tener pocas líneas de código en la clase principal (la que contiene el método `public static void main (String [] args{ }`)

Es mi primera pregunta en StackOverflow en español, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: El código va como texto no como imágenes. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas.

Comment: No te preocupes por las líneas que ocupe tu código. Para esta clase de cosas, depende mucho del programador. Para nombrar variables sí hay convenciones. En general se busca que el código quede bien organizado y legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las 13 líneas de código son de tu clase, tu `método main` tiene 6 líneas que se puede reducir a 3.
Ahora yendo a tu pregunta, normalmente el método main de la clase Principal solamente tiene esa cantidad de líneas de código y a la clase que casi siempre instancia es a `Login`.
Las demás clases si es imposible decirte cuantas líneas de código debe tener, porque más líneas de código no equivale a un mejor programa y por el contrario menos líneas de código no necesariamente nos dice que el programa sea mas eficiente. Lo que si deberías tener el cuenta es si en alguna parte de tu código ves que lo puedas llevar a un método así se aumente las líneas de código entonces hazlo, esto hará tu código más fácil de leer y realizar correcciones.

Por cierto tu código

```
FrmTiposDeUsuarios principal = new FrmTiposDeUsuarios ();
principal .setVisible(true);
```

Se puede escribir como

```
new FrmTiposDeUsuarios ().setVisible(true);
```